# What is the proper way to use Spring beans inside objects which are not managed by Spring container?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a Spring bean (singleton scope if it matters), lets call it FooService.

And I have an object Bar which is not managed by Spring but it want to use FooService.

How to implement this cooperation in the best way? (Let's assume that I don't like the solution with `applicationContext.getBean()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who is constructing the `Bar` instance? You didn't mention this.

If a `Bar` instance requires a `FooService`, then you have to inject the latter into `Bar` with either constructor or setter injection.

If you want `FooService` to be managed by Spring, but not Bar, then you really only have a few options:

1. In the code that constructs the `Bar` instance, pass it a reference to the `FooService` from your applicationContext
2. Just as simple - use Spring to manage the lifecycle of a `Bar` instance as well.

Answer (score 1):

Call "new" in your Bar constructor and create an instance of FooService for it to use.

Comment: FooService is supposed to be a singleton (it's stateless, I don't need multiple instances).

Comment: @Roman - whatever.  Just have a child reference in your Bar object and assign the appropriate reference to FooService.

Answer (score 1):

AOP is an option if you want dependency injection in objects that are not created by an IoC container.  Take a look at Spring's `@Configurable` - I'd paste a link to a Stack Overflow question on the topic, but my cut-n-paste is currently broken.

Comment: See: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable

Answer (score 0):

A Spring bean is ideally a Plain Old Java Object, or a POJO. If it's not Spring managed, then you'll have to manage it yourself. Ideally calling `new`, or something like a `getInstance` method, and then tracking the reference yourself.